# Linking error when calling a function that takes a vector of objects as it's argument

Tags: c++, function, vector, linker

I have a function that takes a vector of objects as it's argument. the function header is:

```
void Evolve(vector <C_Agent> &population)
```

the code compiles properly as long as I don't try to actually call the function. I call it like this:

```
vector <C_Agent> AgentPopulation;
for(int q=0; q < x; q++)
    AgentPopulation.push_back(C_Agent());
Evolve(AgentPopulation);
```

when I try to call it, I get the error:

```
"Evolve(__gnu_debug_def::vector<C_Agent, std::allocator<C_Agent> >)", referenced from:  
main in main.o  
ld: symbol(s) not found  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can eliminate the error by changing the argument to an int instead of a vector of C_Agent.
I have tried commenting out the function body but that doesn't help.

Comment: Well, what's the source file? What is `vector`? (If that's `std::vector`, why do you have a using declaration in a header?) Is the source file being linked?

Comment: __gnu_debug_def::vector doesn't look like std::vector. It looks like there's a typing mismatch. I'd recommend you to explicitely use std::vector, to see whether the error still occurs .

Comment: I think Xcode may have an add-on for that because I just put using in main and it applies it throughout. adding std:: doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nm` from [binutils](http://gnu.org./software/binutils/) is your friend.  It will tell you what symbol `main.o` is trying to reference and what symbol the other object file, with the compiled function definition in, is actually making public.  The mismatch between the twain will lead you to the cause of the mismatch, and thence to the solution to your problem.  You haven't provided enough information for people out here on the World Wide Web to diagnose this for you.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It turns out that in the declaration I had 'population' and in the definition I had '&population'. I guess because I was working with vectors it didn't give me a more obvious error (and let me compile as long as I didn't call the function)?